# Swift: How to trigger functions in Xcode projects?

Tags: swift, function, timer, triggers, call

I am a programming newbie, and I do not know how to trigger my functions in my project. I just need my function to run for 4 seconds, then it doesn't have to work again. I do NOT want a button to call the function, I want it to be automatic! Thanks!

PS. The timer variables is a timer running above.

```
func fadeLabels() {
    if timerCount > 3 {
        timer.invalidate()
        timerRunning = false
    }

    //Label Fade Functionality
    if timerCount == 1 {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.countdownThree.alpha = 0
        })
    }

    if timerCount == 2 {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.countdownTwo.alpha = 0
        })
    }
    if timerCount == 3 {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.countdownOne.alpha = 0
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks to anyone who helps my with my dumb problem!

Comment: Use __switch__ statement instead of __if__

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Check the page to read more about switch: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code in controller's *viewDidLoad* method:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: "fadeLabels", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Comment: I actually added that code to the *viewDidLoad* and only the last **if** statement worked. Any solution?

Comment: F.e. call the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval function three times with different timeout(first parameter)

Comment: I'm happy that I could help you. Please check my answer as "accepted"